# Application icons in system settings disappear after deleting Text Entry

Tags: unity, gnome, apt, icons, language-support

I used to install ibus pinyin in 12.04 following steps as belows:

1. Settings-->Language Support-->Install/Remove Languages, check Chinese item
2. `$ sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-clutter ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-qt4`
3. `$ im-switch -s ibus`
4. Restart
5. `$ sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin`
6. `$ ibus-setup`

It worked. But not in 14.04, and I am facing several issues:

1. Command "im-switch -s ibus" didn't work, system claimed that I need to install im-switch, but that will make "Language Support" disappear. How to make ibus work?
2. Text Entry icon existed on task bar, i thought that's because Text Entry affects ibus; So I deleted Text Entry through Ubuntu Software Center, that made most of default system application icons gone in system settings. Am I able to get them back?

Comment: Thanks for the steps. After `ibus-setup` I can finally type Chinese now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you messed it up a little. ;)

im-switch has been replaced by im-config.

In 14.04 you shouldn't need to install anything to use ibus-pinyin. It's there by default on every Ubuntu installation.

To restore the stuff you unnecessarily removed, please install the ubuntu-desktop package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I also think you should study this page from Ubuntu Desktop Help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: extremely helpful... fresh to Ubuntu and messing up is expected haha >_< i know why i was wrong: i'd added Chinese in text entry instead of adding Chinese(pinyin)

Comment: Do I need logout or restart after installed?

Comment: @quangkid: This is an old question/answer, addressing a very specific situation. Please ask an own question if you need help to set up input methods.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ok, can you please help me with my own question ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069262/ibus-icon-is-suddenly-missing-in-system-tray-ubuntu-16-03-lts

Answer (score 1):

FYI

To restore the Text Entry and other icons in System Settings:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

You don't need to install the whole **ubuntu-desktop** package.

BTW, the icon for input method on menu bar is the **indicator-keyboard** package.

Comment: Do I need logout or restart after install?