# iBus icon is suddenly missing in system tray Ubuntu 16.03 LTS

Tags: 16.04, ibus

I've installed iBus for several days. It's still working fine. However  now its icon doesn't show up when Ubuntu start.

[image]

As below IBus preferences , the icon in System tray setting is enabled
[image]

Can you guy help me this problem?

This is my language support dialog :
[image]

and Text Entry config
[image]

Comment: In _Text Entry_, check the "Show current input source in the menu bar" option. You should normally not need to use _IBus Preferences_ at all.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance that your ibus daemon quit unexpectedly. Try `ibus-daemon &`.